# bind cannot resolve login.live.com

Tags: bind, pi-hole

I am using pihole forwarding to bind as a local dns service.

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Stream release 8
[root@server ~]# named -v
BIND 9.11.36-RedHat-9.11.36-13.el8 (Extended Support Version) <id:68dbd5b>
```

In the past everything worked fine. For some weeks (or maybe longer) I am experiencing problems. Today i tried to resolve login.live.com

My windows PC via pihole:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> nslookup.exe login.live.com
Server:  pi.hole
Address:  192.168.120.10

*** Keine internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA)-Einträge für login.live.com verfügbar.
```

My windows PC via bind:

```
> login.live.com
Server:  server.home.xxxxxx.de
Address:  192.168.2.20

*** login.live.com wurde von server.home.xxxxxx.de nicht gefunden: Unspecified error.
```

On the pihole

```
pi@timeserver:~ $ nslookup login.live.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
;; Connection to 192.168.2.20#53(192.168.2.20) for login.live.com failed: host unreachable.
```

On the bind server:

```
[root@server ~]# nslookup login.live.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
Server:         192.168.2.20
Address:        192.168.2.20#53

Non-authoritative answer:
login.live.com  canonical name = login.msa.msidentity.com.
login.msa.msidentity.com        canonical name = www.tm.lg.prod.aadmsa.akadns.net.
www.tm.lg.prod.aadmsa.akadns.net        canonical name = prdv4a.aadg.msidentity.com.
prdv4a.aadg.msidentity.com      canonical name = www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net.
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 20.190.160.14
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 20.190.160.17
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 40.126.32.138
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 40.126.32.72
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 40.126.32.136
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 40.126.32.68
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 20.190.160.20
Name:   www.tm.v4.a.prd.aadg.akadns.net
Address: 20.190.160.22
```

I am totally clueless what is wrong? Why can bind resolve login.live.com but does not answer when asked from clients?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: pi-hole and bind are working totally fine, except for this query.

Comment: No, all other queries are answered, it is only this query which is not working. The answer "host unreachable" is misleading. And yes ssh and ping is working.